# How to test thread safety of adding to a hashtable?

Tags: multithreading, testing, thread-safety, hashtable

We're using a hashtable to store sessions in a web service. I want to test thread safety of adding to this session. I wrote a Console App which generates lots of threads and adds to this session. But I am neither getting an exception nor losing any data.
Am I doing anything wrong or isn't this much of operation a threat to hashtable?!

- The key is generated randomly.
- The operations done on this hashtable are fairly simple: Add, Remove, ContainsKey, [] (getting an entry) and sometimes updating the value of an entry - no foreach or loop.

  ```
  private const int Threads = 10000;
  private const int SleepLimit = 10000;


  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
      try
      {
          Console.WriteLine("Application Started.");


      Thread[] threads = new Thread[Threads];
      for (int i = 0; i &lt; threads.Length; i++)
          threads[i] = CreateThread();


      Console.WriteLine("All Threads Started.");


      foreach (Thread t in threads)
          t.Join();


      Console.WriteLine("All Threads Joined.");
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
      Console.WriteLine("Exception occurred: " + ex.Message);
      Console.ReadLine();
  }


  }


  private static Thread CreateThread()
  {
      Thread thread = new Thread(UserFunction);
      thread.Start();
      return thread;
  }


  private static void UserFunction()
  {
      Thread.Sleep(_random.Next(SleepLimit));
      SessionManagement.AddSession("Test");
  }


  public static void AddSession(string session)
  {
      ulong hash = NextHashValue();
      while (_sessionPool.ContainsKey(hash))
      {
          Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Duplicate Session Key: {0}-PoolSize: {1}",
              hash, _sessionPool.Count);


      hash = NextHashValue();
  }


  _sessionPool.Add(hash, session);


  if (!_sessionPool.ContainsKey(hash))
      Console.WriteLine("Race problem occurred - Session Key: " + hash);


  }
  ```

Comment: this approach works with Dictionary<K,T>. If you access it this way, it starts throwing exceptions soon

Comment: Do you mean the `Hashtable` class provided by the BCL (and documented as not being threadsafe) or a custom hashtable?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you re going to such trouble to verify that concurrent writes to `Hashtable` are going to crash your app.

Even if your test app runs safely for a long time, you should not deploy code that does not protect your `Hashtable` from writes that are concurrent with other read or write operations.

10000 threads is a very large number, by the way - I hope your production app does not plan on using this many.

Comment: I need them to show to my project manager. Because such a problem, if has ever occurred, cannot be found in our logs. Besides, this product has more users than this, and increasing.

Comment: @reticent - you can show your project manager the problem in the 'Thread Safety' section of the MSDN docs at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

The only way I know how to test this is by slowly reviewing all the possible thread/lock interaction in the source code or on a piece of paper.

A long time ago I had an app with 8 threads interacting between them, and it crashed about once time a week of constant use. After a few of these crashes I started to suspect a threading issue. So I managed to simplify a lot the locking code, and then I proved on a piece of paper that all the possible thread/lock interactions were safe. The issue disappeared.

Comment: That's right, it helps a lot. On the paper, it seems possible to have corrupt data, but we haven't had crashes or specific data losses, even in tests. Maybe the problem lies in what I'm looking for to prove the unsafety.